# Sending FCM Notifications to multiple devices (but not all devices) in C#.net

Tags: c#, android, .net, push-notification

I am using FCM Notifications in my android app.
the notification has to be sent to sent to a limited number of users (around 200 users) at the same time using .net pages

```
    public static void SendPushNotification()
    {

        try
        {

            string applicationID = "ABC****xyz";

            string senderId = "01*****89";

            string deviceId1 = "def****jdk";
            string deviceId2 = "lej****wka";
            string deviceId3 = "fqx****pls";

            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                //This line is the problem
                to = deviceId1+","+deviceId2+","+deviceId3,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Notification Body",
                    title = "Notification Title",
                    sound = "Enabled",
                    icon = "MyIcon"

                }
            };
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            string str = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string str = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

The ***to*** line is problem is where I concatenate multiple devices
How can I just send the notifications for these devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sending push notification to multiple devices, you have to use 'registration_ids' instead of 'to' parameter that contains array of device tokens. The limitation is that you can provide a maximum of 1000 device tokens by this method. Check this out for reference [FCM Downstream Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream)